# Android custom view like crumpled paper

Tags: android, android-custom-view

Is it possible to create a custom view that looks like a piece of slightly crumpled paper on Android? (i.e. something that looks like the below image and then add text on top of it.) How can we go about making the creases in the paper like in the below image?

[image: Crumpled paper background]

Any help would be much appreciated.

TIA

Comment: You can just use that image and pop it in an ImageView, right? It would use less CPU cycles than using an algorithm to draw a similar effect in a CustomView..

Comment: Be very careful using full image backgrounds though. This will hurt performance, especially if you use an extremely large drawable file.

Comment: I would like to animate this after overlaying some text on in. Animate it like in a crumpling action or a paper tearing action etc. Any idea how that could be done?

Answer (score 0):

better save this texture to your drawable and use drawBitmap on the canvas. then you can draw whatever you want over it.

[Canvas.drawBitmap(....)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap, android.graphics.Rect, android.graphics.Rect, android.graphics.Paint))

Comment: Thanks. Will try that. Btw do you know how this can then be animated for instance like a crumpling animation of the paper or a tearing animation?

Comment: Maybe you can draw several frames of this image to animate on touch or with a frame rate. But be careful for heavy operations you can block your main thread. To avoid this use surfaceview instead of view. Here is a good example of bouncing ball. it will give you an idea how to do it.

Comment: the link that i forgot:) http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/bouncing-a-ball-on-androids-canvas/